# ArangoDB graph feature vs GraphQL

Tags: graphql, arangodb, graphql-js, catalog

I am trying to design a product catalog which contains several features for the product (e.g., size, color, producer, etc).

I am also using the Arango Database as my database. The ArangoDB provides a powerful graph traversal feature. In this regard, I would like to know if it would be better to take advantage of the Arango graph traversal feature, or use the graphQL.

I have been researching about graphQL and I honestly can't see how it is more beneficial than the ArangoDB graph traversal capabilities.

Answer (score 1):

The graph traversal of ArangoDB is much more performant than graphQL. The only reason to pick graphQL is that it is a little bit easier to implement.

ArangoDB has recently created a graphQL AQL generator. Maybe this could be interesting for you.
https://www.arangodb.com/2017/10/auto-generate-graphql-arangodb/